# animation and data bindings

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I need an help with animations, i tried to set by code the value of an SplineDoubleKeyFrame by data binding, but it doesn't work, why? 
Code xaml:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,435,0,0">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetName="barra" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />

                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0 1,0" Value="{Binding linea1}" KeyTime="0:0:0.8" />

                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.10, 0.21 0.00, 1.0" Value="{Binding linea1}"  KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="12,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="#FF8E76FF" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" StrokeThickness="5"/>
            <Rectangle Visibility="Visible" x:Name="barra" Fill="#FF8E76FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="12,-72,0,0" Stroke="#FF8E76FF" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

c#:

```
linea1 = 440;
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: Show the C# class not just the line of code.

Comment: Share the the Property declaration for linea1?
What is the DataContext of your StackPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **DataBinding** you need to use **Property** only .you cannot use varibale for binding(for ex: var linea1 = 440;)

To create property I create a class

```
  public class StackpanelProperties
{
    public int linea1 { get; set; }
}
```

And set datacontext to Stackpnael so that I can use this property for binding

```
this.InitializeComponent();
stack.DataContext = new StackpanelProperties() { linea1 = 440 };
```

**xaml code**

```
<StackPanel Name="stack" Margin="0,435,0,0">
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.8" EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="barra" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0 1,0" Value="{Binding linea1}" KeyTime="0:0:0.8" />
                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.10, 0.21 0.00, 1.0" Value="{Binding linea1}"  KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="12,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="#FF8E76FF" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" StrokeThickness="5"/>
    <Rectangle Visibility="Visible" x:Name="barra" Fill="#FF8E76FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="12,-72,0,0" Stroke="#FF8E76FF" StrokeThickness="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Note :** [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded) is used for begin animation on stackpnael Loaded event.